# python regex os path

Tags: python, regex, path, operating-system, find

I am trying to find directories that follow the below pattern and any instances of mbojava that reside within:

/v/mybooks.com/***somethign that keeps changing***/mbo(with or without a proceeding 'c[1-9]')/

I also wish to avoid names that follow with a dot, eg mbo not mbo.prev mboc3 not mboc3.broken,etc

I have the following so far:

```
regex = re.compile("\/mbo(c[1-9])?\/"
mbojava = False
for root, dirs, names in os.walk("/v/mybooks.com/"):
   if 'mbojava' in names and regex.search(root):
      mbojava =  os.path.join(root, 'mbojava')
      print mbojava
```

Result:

I only get one line  when I know for certain that there are multiple directories that follow the above pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use os/re.  Use glob.glob as the way to do it.

```
import glob
paths = glob.glob(r'/v/mybooks.com/*/mbo[1-9]')
```

Comment: what if I want to add `/v/mybooks.com/` using f-sttring as a string variable?

Comment: @FaridAlijani - Then you need to use both f and r in glob() function call, like `glob.glob(fr"{dir_regex_module}")`.